# Is it possible to change BootstrapDialog title and other properties from the remote file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to open a BootstrapDialog and load a remote page inside (PHP, CFM or whatever). I want to know if it's possible to change dialog properties (mainly the TITLE) from that loaded page. I tried to insert the following code but It doesn't work:

```
<script>
$('#openedDialog').setTitle('Blah, blah');
</script>
```

If I add:

```
alert($('#openedDialog'))
```

it works. So the object exists, it's just I don't have access to its methods.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `bootstrap modal` the title element is using `h4 tag`  with a `class modal-title`.So you can use `text` instead of `setTitle`

```
$('.modal-title').text("new title")
```

and if you are using [this bootstrap dialog plugin](https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/) then use

```
$('.bootstrap-dialog-title').text("new title")
```

or

```
var dialogInstance = new BootstrapDialog();
dialogInstance.setTitle('new title');
```

else if you given a `id` to the title then

```
$('#myTitleID').text("new title")
```

Comment: I am not using Bootstrap modal, I am using this - https://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/

Comment: so instead of `.modal-Title` use `.bootstrap-dialog-title`

Comment: .bootstrap-dialog-title fixed the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @AdrianCiocălău you can also use .setTitle as you did, but on dialog instance, not DOM object

Comment: @Sojtin you are also absolutely correct.I have updated my answer.Thank you for your inputs.